# Access variables from specific class over ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called `Questions` which has two subclasses `multipleChoice` and `FillInBlank`. These two sub-classes each have unique instance variables.

Now let's say I have an `ArrayList <Questions> questions` which store both types of questions (`multipleChoice` and `FillInBlank`).

My question is: When I iterate through the questions ArrayList, how do I access particular instance variables from the `multipleChoice` class and the `FillInBlank` class? I am having trouble because the type of the arraylist is type questions.

Comment: You will need to explain more about what you want to do when iterating. Generally, a consumer of a class does not access instance variables directly.

Comment: Besides the "main" answer in the pointed topic, also check the other one with `instanceof`, that's how you can check which kind of question you are looking at.

Comment: If you have problems like that, I don't believe that you're using the right abstractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `instanceof` should be used to identify which subclass is the current element, and then this element should be cast to this subclass:

```java
for (Questions question : questions) {
    if (question instanceof MultipleChoice) {
        doSomething((MultipleChoice) question);
    } else if (question instanceof FillInBlank) {
        doSomething((FillInBlank) question);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unexpected class: " + question.getClass());
    }
}

// ...
private void doSomething(MultipleChoice mc) {
    // do something
    System.out.println(mc.getChoice());
}

private void doSomething(FillInBlank fib) {
    // do something
    System.out.println(fib.getFilledAnswer());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Automatic casting for `instanceof`

The [Answer by Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67012168/642706) is correct.

[Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16) simplifies that code, with the arrival of [JEP 394: Pattern Matching for `instanceof`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394). The [downcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) becomes automatic.

Since casting immediately after a call to `instanceof` is so common:

```java
if ( obj instanceof String ) {
    String s = (String) obj;    // grr...
    ...
}
```

… pattern matching technology now allows for implicit casting. Notice the introduction of a variable name within the `if ( instanceof )` test.

```java
if ( obj instanceof String s ) {  // <-- Implicit downcast to a named variable.
    // Let pattern matching do the work!
    ...
}
```

(By the way, your `Questions` class should be named as singular rather than plural given your description: `Question`.)

Using this feature, the code seen in that other Answer becomes:

```java
for ( Question question : questions ) {
    if ( question instanceof MultipleChoice q ) {
        doSomething( q ) ;
    } else if ( question instanceof FillInBlank q ) {
        doSomething( q ) ;
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Unexpected class: " + question.getClass() ) ;
    }
}
…
private void doSomething( MultipleChoice mc ) {
    // do something
    System.out.println( mc.getChoice() );
}

private void doSomething( FillInBlank fib ) {
    // do something
    System.out.println( fib.getFilledAnswer() );
}
```

### Full example code

Here is a complete example to run, in a single file.

```java
package com.work.demo.casting;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App2
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App2 app = new App2();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < Question > questions =
                List.of(
                        new MultipleChoice() ,
                        new FillInBlank() ,
                        new FillInBlank()
                );
        //System.out.println( "questions = " + questions );

        for ( Question question : questions )
        {
            if ( question instanceof MultipleChoice q )
            {
                doSomething( q );
            } else if ( question instanceof FillInBlank q )
            {
                doSomething( q );
            } else
            {
                System.out.println( "Unexpected class: " + question.getClass() );
            }
        }
    }

    private void doSomething ( MultipleChoice mc )
    {
        // … do something …
        System.out.println( mc.getChoice() );
    }

    private void doSomething ( FillInBlank fib )
    {
        // … do something …
        System.out.println( fib.getFilledAnswer() );
    }
}

abstract class Question
{
    public final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) { return "Question[id=" + id + "]"; }
}

final class MultipleChoice extends Question
{
    public String getChoice ( ) { return "some choice response. ID: " + this.id; }
}

final class FillInBlank extends Question
{
    public String getFilledAnswer ( ) { return "some filled answer response. ID: " + this.id; }
}
```

When run.

```
some choice response. ID: bf418995-2d33-47c8-8276-06442330337a
some filled answer response. ID: 3fef17a3-9f46-463f-8e80-5361df6089bc
some filled answer response. ID: 1f2cb1e0-6142-49f2-96b8-888ded1210db
```

## Sealed classes

In the future, the [upcoming sealed classes feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/397) may help further simplify such code.